# Метод простых итераций для нелинейного уравнения C++

Tags: c++, математика, анализ

Требуется написать функцию поиска корня решения нелинейного уравнения (

> x^3 - 3*x^2 - 18*x + 54

), используя метод простых итераций, на заданных отрезках `[-4.25; -4.2], [3; 3.05], [4.2; 4.25]` с точностью `eps = 1e-9`. Не понимаю как выразить x = fi(x), пытался выразить через:

> (x^3 - 3*x^2 + 54) / 18

Но данная формула считает правильно только для второго отрезка. Интересует реализация данного метода на языке c++

Comment: Посмотрите [условие сходимости](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B4_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B9_%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8#%D0%A3%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D1%81%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8) — вы должны преобразовать к такому виду, чтоб оно выполнялось... В крайнем случае можно сводить просто к методу Ньютона, хотя тут вопрос — некоторые считают, что это тоже метод итераций, а некоторые нет...

Comment: Вдогонку... При не совсем корректно подобранном уравнении может быть так, что, начав с точки в одном диапазоне, выскочите в корень в другом...

Comment: В жизни не делал такого. Заинтересовался и попечатал значения исходной формулы с шагом s = 0.001 по х. Наверное вы правы и функцию надо во что-то преобразовывать, но навскидку у меня получилось, что если использовать исходную, то все очень просто. Надо найти x, при котором функция меняет знак и с уменьшенным шагом пройти тем же циклом между x - s и x.  Потом повторять это, пока не найдем отличие от 0.0 c нужной точностью. Вот и все. (кстати, на втором диапазоне функция равна 0 на левой границе и такой случай надо отдельно проверять)